# Angular throws errors whenever JQuery is included

Tags: angularjs, systemjs

---

*NOTE*

[This is a link to a sample application that reproduces the issue](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10121209/AngularAndJQueryTest.rar)

---

I am using SystemJS, JSPM, Angular and jQuery in an ASP.Net 4.6 application. However, whenever I try to include jQuery in the app, I get module load errors.

I uploaded a simple app to reproduce the issue to dropbox here: [Simple App That Reproduces Issue](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10121209/AngularAndJQueryTest.rar)

(you will need Visual Studio 2015 to run)

Essentially, in the project there is a file /scripts/app/app.js that looks like this:

```
import 'jquery';
import "angular";

var ByobApp = angular.module("ByobApp", []);
```

When you try and run the app when the code looks like this, you will see these errors (Chrome screenshot):

[image: Module Load Errors]

However, when you change the code to this:

```
//import 'jquery';
import "angular";

var ByobApp = angular.module("ByobApp", []);
```

(commenting out jQuery import). The application will load just fine.

Obviously something is wrong with the jQuery import. But I cannot tell what!

Any help would be great.

---

**EDIT**

Based on comments, I changed _Layout.cshtml to look like this (including JQuery and Angular without trying to load it with SystemJs):

```
<script src="~/scripts/jspm_packages/npm/jquery@2.2.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jspm_packages/github/angular/bower-angular@1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.baseURL = "/scripts";
</script>
```

And I made app.js look like this:

```
//import 'jquery';
//import "angular";

var ByobApp = angular.module("ByobApp", []);
```

The error is the same.

---

**EDIT 2**

If I include the Zepto library instead, it works fine. Zepto is a 1:1 replacement for the jQuery API, so using it is exactly the same!

Comment: it is safer add a <script> tag on the HTML where you are loading the scripts instead of importing them. Dynamics imports is very useful for projects with a lot of dependencies. For core libraries like jqyery and angular, I advise you to load them via HTML tag,

Comment: On top of that, I advise not loading jQuery at all, if you're using Angular.

Comment: This is a simplification from a more complex app. I have not been able to get it to work using a script tag, either using the example app i posted.

Comment: Isn't it called jQuery with a capital Q?

Comment: @devqon it is mapped in config.js like this: "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.2.0",

Comment: Have you tried a different version of JQuery?  If only to see if the same error persists?  If it doesn't, there might be some competition for how JQ2.2.0 and NG are trying to initialize for the $ namespace.

Comment: @jusopi yes, I have. Back to 1.9.x

Comment: I have a similar setup, however I'm not using SystemJS, instead I'm using Node/Browserify to build my app.  If you're using a script tag for your Jquery, I believe it's already present without you having to say `import 'jquery'`.  Then again I'm not sure how your dependencies get resolved with the `import` statement.  You say it works when that's commented out, you can test if you're indeed using JQ or JQLite by testing some of the `angular.element` APIs to see if you can use full selectors for those labeled restricted in the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Actually you can test to see if Angular is using the full JQuery by doign this in your console: `angular.element === windowjQuery`

Comment: (has anyone even *tried* the test app I made?)

Comment: what if you try to use `angular.bootstrap(document, ['ByobApp'])` instead using `ng-app` to bootstrap the app? (I had similar problem under IE and that helped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR

It looks like an angular bug (maybe specific to the 1.4.8 version and system.js usage).
The solution is to bootstrap the application [manually](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization).

### Error analysis

The problem is that when angular app is bootstrapped with `ng-app`:

```
<body ng-app="ByobApp">
    ...
</body>
```

The application code loads `jquery` before `angular` (using system.js):

```
import 'jquery';
import "angular";
var ByobApp = angular.module("ByobApp", []);
```

And angular raises an error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
Failed to instantiate module ByobApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ByobApp' is not available!
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies
as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=ByobApp
```

It works if jquery import is removed or even if we swap jquery and angular:

```
import "angular";
import 'jquery';  // it works if jquery is second
var ByobApp = angular.module("ByobApp", []);
```

### The workaround

The solution is to initialize the angular application manually:

```
<!-- do not include ng-app="ByobApp" here -->
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        ...
    </nav>

    <script src="/scripts/jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.baseURL = "/scripts";
        System['import']('app/app').then(function() {
            // Manually bootstrap once application is loaded.
            // This code can be in the app.js as well, but it should
            // be at the end (when everything else is defined).
            angular.element(document).ready(function () {
              angular.bootstrap(document, ['ByobApp']);
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Test code:

- [index_bug.html](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/angular-jquery-load-problem/index_bug.html) - version which raises an error
- [index.html](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/angular-jquery-load-problem/index.html) - working version, click 'Home' to send message from one controller to another
- [app.js](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/angular-jquery-load-problem/scripts/app/app.js) - application code

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This solution worked brilliantly. Great analysis, very thorough answer.

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is (unfortunately) to be expected when using modules to load Angular. From the documentation on [initialization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap):

> Angular initializes automatically upon `DOMContentLoaded` event or when the `angular.js` script is evaluated if at that time `document.readyState` is set to `'complete'`.

In the modules case, Angular is loaded when `document.readyState` is `'complete'`.

> At this point Angular looks for the ng-app directive which designates your application root. If the ng-app directive is found then Angular will:
>
> - load the module associated with the directive
> - ...

Remember, Angular is loaded as a dependency of `app.js`, so it executed *before* `app.js`, i.e. the `ByobApp` does not exist! So the first step above fails and you get the error.

You *must* use manual initialization (as suggested in the comment from Etsitra) - the only way to use Angular with module loaders AFAIK. This works:

- remove ng-app from your main HTML file
- add the following to app.js:

  ```
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['ByobApp']);
  ```

Comment: The solution is what you suggested (manual initialization), but it still looks like a bug. If `jquery` import is commented out or placed after the `angular` import then the issue is gone. It looks like something works when angular users own jqlite implementation and breaks when it switches to jquery.